# Enabling download all with server = TRUE datatable by using invisible download button

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

The goal is to enable download all data from datatable even when `server = TRUE`. I'm very close already thanks to [this post](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/267#issuecomment-624796199) on Github.

This works:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- JS(
  "var a = document.createElement('a');",
  "$(a).addClass('dt-button');",
  "a.href = document.getElementById('download1').href;",
  "a.download = '';",
  "$(a).attr('target', '_blank');",
  "$(a).text('Download');",
  "$('div.dwnld').append(a);",
  "$('#download1').hide();"
)

ui <- basicPage(
  downloadButton("download1", ""), # no label: this button will be hidden
  numericInput("nrows", "Number of rows", 10),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$dtable <- renderDT(
    datatable(iris[1:input$nrows,],
              callback = callback,
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(
                dom = 'B<"dwnld">frtip',
                buttons = list(
                  "copy"
                )
              )
    )
  )
  
  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(iris, file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The problem is that the download button is briefly visible on app load. How do I ensure the download button is always invisible?

I tried using `shinyjs::hidden()`, but it causes the download to fail:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

callback <- JS(
  "var a = document.createElement('a');",
  "$(a).addClass('dt-button');",
  "a.href = document.getElementById('download1').href;",
  "a.download = '';",
  "$(a).attr('target', '_blank');",
  "$(a).text('Download');",
  "$('div.dwnld').append(a);",
  "$('#download1').hide();"
)

ui <- basicPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  hidden(downloadButton("download1", "")), # no label: this button will be hidden
  numericInput("nrows", "Number of rows", 10),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$dtable <- renderDT(
    datatable(iris[1:input$nrows,],
              callback = callback,
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(
                dom = 'B<"dwnld">frtip',
                buttons = list(
                  "copy"
                )
              )
    )
  )
  
  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(iris, file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## EDIT

Using `div(style = 'display: none;', ...)` also results in a failed download.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- JS(
  "var a = document.createElement('a');",
  "$(a).addClass('dt-button');",
  "a.href = document.getElementById('download1').href;",
  "a.download = '';",
  "$(a).attr('target', '_blank');",
  "$(a).text('Download');",
  "$('div.dwnld').append(a);",
  "$('#download1').hide();"
)

ui <- basicPage(
  div(style = "display: none;", downloadButton("download1", "")), # no label: this button will be hidden
  numericInput("nrows", "Number of rows", 10),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$dtable <- renderDT(
    datatable(iris[1:input$nrows,],
              callback = callback,
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(
                dom = 'B<"dwnld">frtip',
                buttons = list(
                  "copy"
                )
              )
    )
  )
  
  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(iris, file)
    }
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `downloadButton("download1", "", style = "visibility: hidden;")`

Comment: @YBS This works well! If you convert this comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `hidden` style in the `downloadButton` as shown below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

callback <- JS(
  "var a = document.createElement('a');",
  "$(a).addClass('dt-button');",
  "a.href = document.getElementById('download1').href;",
  "a.download = '';",
  "$(a).attr('target', '_blank');",
  "$(a).text('Download');",
  "$('div.dwnld').append(a);",
  "$('#download1').hide();"
)

ui <- basicPage(
  # useShinyjs(),
  # hidden(downloadButton("download1", "")), # no label: this button will be hidden
  downloadButton("download1", "", style = "visibility: hidden;"),
  numericInput("nrows", "Number of rows", 10),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$dtable <- renderDT(
    datatable(iris[1:input$nrows,],
              callback = callback,
              extensions = 'Buttons',
              options = list(
                dom = 'B<"dwnld">frtip',
                buttons = list(
                  "copy"
                )
              )
    )
  )

  output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(iris, file)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the button in an invisible `div` :

```
ui <- basicPage(
  div(
    style = "display: none;",
    downloadButton("download1", ""), # no label: this button will be hidden
  ),
  numericInput("nrows", "Number of rows", 10),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)
```

Comment: Please see edit. This works to hide the download button, but then the download fails.